# need to disable <mat-form-field> focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular material and trying to built a small form.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline" >
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

But a small problem I'm facing- When I m giving appearance="outline", the input fields are outlined when doing hover/focus. I wish to remove the hover/focus behavior.

```
https://eaadmxqgrggv.angular.stackblitz.io/
```

Can someone help me to resolve this or give an insight how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 2):

This CSS should do the job:

```css
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end,
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
        border-width: 1px !important;
        color: #e0e0e0;
    }
```

PS.: Setting `encapsulation` to `ViewEncapsulation.None` should be avoided, use **::ng-deep** in CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

To set a border for the input, include the following in your component.ts:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ....
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

In css

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
   color: rgba(0,0,0,.12);
   border:0
}
```

Comment: My stackblitz: https://eaadmxqgrggv.angular.stackblitz.io/
When I hovering on the fields, a outline is coming. I want to remove that line

Comment: @SajjadTabreez ur stackblitz not opening

Comment: I will connect with you tomorrow.Had to go native